# Rotate image and with loss of quality

Tags: c++, gtk3, cairo

I have this code that rotates an image. But the result is an image with a transparency effect (https://pixs.ru/image/G82BPR - like this) that accumulates with each call to this function. I want to get the image on the output in its original form, but inverted and have no idea what to do. Thanks if you have any advice.

```
bool rotate_sticker(GdkEventScroll* scroll, const unsigned int inx) {
    
Gtk::Image* img = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Image*>(small_stickers[inx]->get_child());
Glib::RefPtr< Gdk::Pixbuf > old_pixbuf = img->get_pixbuf(); 
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window> win = small_stickers[inx]->get_window();

Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Region> region = Cairo::Region::create();

Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DrawingContext> draw_context = win->begin_draw_frame(region);


const double degree = 5;
const double w = 135;
const double h = 135;

Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> surface = Cairo::ImageSurface::create(Cairo::Format::FORMAT_ARGB32,w,h);
Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> cr = Cairo::Context::create(surface);


//rotate by central point

cr->translate (w*0.5, h*0.5);
cr->rotate_degrees(degree);
cr->translate (-0.5*w, -0.5*h);

Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cr,old_pixbuf);
cr->paint();

win->end_draw_frame(draw_context);
img->set(Gdk::Pixbuf::create(cr->get_target(),0,0,w,h));

return true;
}
```

Comment: To stop the effect accumulating can't you keep the original image and always calculate each new rotational position from that?

Comment: Yes, i can, if i save the rotation rate for each image. In principle, this solution fits, Thanks!